# React UseState hook, unable to concatenate arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am encountering some strange behavior when attempting to add two arrays together in react.
Each array chunk has a length of 50 items. My list never grows beyond 50.

I have tried both with spread operator and concat method, with and without wrapper functions.
nothing works

```
setWordList(wordList => wordList.concat(msg))
setWordList(wordList => [...wordList, msg]) 
setWordList([...wordList, msg]) 
setWordList(wordList.concat(msg))
```

```
  const [wordList, setWordList] = useState([])
  const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(true)


  
  const loadMoreList = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    setIsSearching(true)
    let already = []
    for(let i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++){
      already.push({_id: wordList[i]._id})
    }
    console.log(already)
    socket.current.emit('get word list more', {filter: data.filter, already: already});
  }

  

  socket.current.on('word list in', (msg) => {
  
    setWordList(wordList => [...wordList, msg])
    
    console.log(msg)
    setIsSearching(false)
   
  });
```

Example data(array length = 50)

```
[{
definition: "1. aufhören zu leben, sein Leben beschließen↵Beispiele↵“jung sterben”↵Wendungen, Redensarten, Sprichwörter↵“zum Sterben langweilig, müde, einsam o. Ä...."
id: "dfe03030-0c50-11ea-afa4-098be982e090"
leitner_no: 2
priority: true
priority_time: 1587986213134
reviews: 1
source: "manual"
source_details: "none"
time_stamp: 1583402873665
word: "sterben  | starb, gestorben |"
_id: "fb99b7c3-34a4-4e63-a98e-41efbbcfe5fc"}]
```

The current list and incoming data never concatenate, the new data seems to replace that in the list already. `Console.log` of `wordList` within `socket('word list in')` returns an empty list regardless of whether there is data rendered from the previous input. Somehow the state appears to not be persisting.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both the array needs to be spread, like this:

```
setWordList(wordList => [...wordList, ...msg])
```

Comment: is it me or we got used to this horrific stuff because of too much javascript?
I would never expect this behaviour in any other language, and would drop that language the second I saw this, it is just that the web hooked us all to JS ????

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a single array with the concatenated items you would use :

```
setWordList(wordList => [...wordList, ...msg])
```

and the outcome would be : ["banana", "orange", "apple", "..."];

However if you were looking to have an array of arrays...then you would want to :

```
setWordList(wordList => [...wordList, msg])
```

Then the outcome would be : [[...array1],[...array2],[...whatever]];